# Which is the better way to remove self from NSNotificationCenter? Just remove self or remove self from the specific notification name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, dealloc

I just want to know: Which is the better way to remove self from NSNotificationCenter in **dealloc** method? Or is anyone have met different behaviors between the two way?

Just remove self by follow code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

or remove self from the specific notification name like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NotificationName object:someObj];
```

**PS.** I just catch a weird thing that when I remove self from notification center by the first way but the object which is dealloced still can receive the notification, and this call a crash exception of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

that will remove all registrations where the observer is `self`

`UIViewController` could have its own registrations that it doesn't want removed in `viewWillDisappear`:. It's unlikely to register for any of the notifications in the public API using `addObserver:selector:name:object:`, because that would preclude you registering for them in your `UIViewController` subclass, but it could certainly register for non-public notifications now or in a future version.

A safe way to deregister is to send `removeObserver:name:object:` once for each registration:

```
- (void)deregisterForNotifications {
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center removeObserver:self name:someNotification object:nil];
object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in dealloc, its better to use

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

otherwise always use

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NotificationName object:someObj];
```

---

In Xcode, put the cursor on this method and see the quick help on right panel.

Comment: Is it okay to use `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];`
in ViewDidAppear?

Comment: not recommend that. because it will remove observer even thought super class still need it.